# Discriminant of p-adic $\mathbb{Q}_{p}[\phi]$, where $0=f(\phi)=\phi^{p}-\phi-1$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

Any suggestions using the minimal polynomial?

How about $D_{\mathbb{Q}_{p}[\phi]/\mathbb{Q}_{p}}=(-1)N_{\mathbb{Q}_{p}[\phi],\mathbb{Q}_{p}}(f')$?
But foremost I prefer you suggest me a correct method. I want to avoid the computational approach.

The approach is to find the change of basis matrix. The basis is $\{1,\phi,...,\phi^{p-1}\}$ and we take a random element $a=a_{1}+a_{2}\phi+...+a_{p-1}\phi^{p-1}$. Then multiply it by each of the basis elements and represent it in the basis form to get the matrix. Then evaluate that determinant.

Comment: The [companion matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix) is actually very simple to write down and compute the $\det$ of.

Comment: I am guessing cuz the matrix will be pXp